# running android app on emulator using emulator device wifi

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation, android-wifi

My app's functionality is sending/receiving messages to home automation device.here for connection purpose  I'm using **`wifi`** to connect device. app is working fine in mobile device but for test  to work on all device  I'm  using emulator but issue is while running first activity app tests for **wifi** if wifi is not **`ON`** it will show message to on the **wifi** but in emulator after
making wifi on then I am not able to see any **wifi** connections that's why app is not running...if emulator using system wifi then I will not get "on the wifi message" I don't know what to do next?

Answer (score 1):

In [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com) emulator you can simulate the WIFI.

Or you can also mock the WIFI in your code, if you run it on an emulator.